# Why is the SqlCmd MSBuild Task throwing an error when run with TFS team build?

Tags: msbuild

I asked this over at [the MSBuild Extension Pack site](http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/), but I figured I would try to get some more eyes on it, in case someone else has had a similar experience:

I have a pretty straightforward task that should execute a series of sql script files in a folder. (The task is in a file called OperationalDB.msbuild).  The task looks like this:

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.SqlServer.SqlCmd
    TaskAction="Execute"
    Server="$(SqlServerName)"
    Database="$(SqlCatalogName)"
    InputFiles="@(OperationalStaticDataFiles)"
/>
```

It fails when running as part of a TFS 2008 team build.  The log error says:

C:\b\56\S\Main\Builds\OperationalDB.msbuild : warning : Exit Code 1. Failure: Sqlcmd: Error: Internal error at ReadTextLine (Reason: Unspecified error).

Worse, (from a debugging perspective), if I log in to my build server with the same account that the team build service is running, and run OperationalDB.msbuild through MSBuild from a command line, it works beautifully.  No errors, all the SQL executes.

My understanding of the task is that it wraps the SQLCmd console app.  So I tried running that on the build server as well.  It also worked.  The variable in the mix seems to be TFS Team Build.  But it's not giving me insight of how to investigate it -- just the error listed above.

Any ideas?

Comment: First, if i had to put money on it, I'd bet you're making assumptions about the accounts performing these actions and that the cause of the problem is some security setting or another.  Second, I'd highly suggest running Profiler on the TFS sql server to see who is doing what and how.  Five minutes with Profiler will probably reveal the problem.

Comment: Will,
That was a good call, but it still didn't get me over the hump.  The SQL trace indicated something interesting: the identity that I was expecting was making the SQL call, but the commands were not coming through.  Instead of T-SQL, it was (apparently) sending an empty string to SQL Server.  That got me revved, because I thought it was going to be something with file paths.  I figured that team build was forcing a different method of resolving file paths on the SQLCmd task.  I went so far as to hard code the path on the dev server to the SQL files, but even that didn't solve it.

Comment: (cont) 
Alas, I figured I had given enough of my time to the issue and went for a workaround.  I built a little batch file that found the sql scripts, looped through them, and passed them to the SQLCmd console app one by one.  I then used an Exec task to run the batch file from MSBuild.  Worked like a charm, but still left me feeling unsatisfied.  Maybe when I get some free time, I'll dive into the task's source code.

Comment: I get this same error when trying to pipe a file into sqlcmd within a cygwin bash environment (but not in a cmd shell).  My suspicion is that there is something 'odd' / different going on in the way that cygwin's bash generated the pipe into sqlcmd such that sqlcmd doesn't like it.  Maybe MSBuild suffers the same issue?  Not much to go I, I know,...  Similar to you, I simply pushed the text to a temp file and then used the -i option to consume it - worked fine then.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/q/267767/164429 which might be a duplicate.